# C++ Code is running slower over time

Tags: c++, runtime

I have a long C++ program consisting of thousands of lines of codes, several classes, functions etc. The program basically reads info from an input file, runs an algorithm, and writes the results in output files.

Today I realized that run time of the program drastically changes from time to time. So I do a small test by restarting my computer, closing every other thing possible, and running the code  5 times in a row using the same input file. The run times are 50, 80, 130, 180, 190 seconds, respectively.

My first guess in this situation is the non-deleted dynamic memories. But I have been using dynamic arrays just twice in the whole code, and I am sure I delete those arrays.

Do you guys have any explanation for this? I am using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 computer.

Comment: You're sure you've deleted the arrays, but are you sure they are *really* deleted?

Comment: You ran the program fresh each time? Did you ensure that the previous instance exited (e.g. in the Task Manager)?

Comment: Could be many things, but some sort of "leak"/"buildup" or possibly fragmentation seems the most likely scenario. Try running a profiler on your code and see where the difference is.

Comment: Do you use pointers? In your whole codebase find all calls to 'new' and make sure there is a 'delete' for that new.

Comment: easier to just see if your total memory usage goes up over time at an unreasonable pace...

Comment: Is this code performing any file io that accumulates *between* runs? I.e. a file is used for both input and output, linearly searched, and grows with each execution?

Comment: There have to be some Valgrind equivalents for Visual Studio. Don't guess, just check it for leaks.

Comment: There are a lot of causes for this kind of behavior most of which involve accumulating resources thereby adding more and more overhead to the application executing.  However what resources it may be is nothing more than a guessing game without additional information about the application, how it is being used, how the application is accumulating resources, and what resources and operating environment the application is running within.

Comment: Keep testing, removing/isolating/mocking out parts of your program until the problem goes away. Then you'll know what to blame and this'll be a much easier problem to solve.

Comment: @PawelZubrycki there definitely are such formalities in the VCRT (a different path must be taken if you're using WIN32 heaps rather than `malloc()` or `operator new()`, but it is still doable). For CRT-based allocations `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` can help, but ultimately setting the "dump-on-exit" flag (`_CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF`) and running in debug-mode is the real ticket, not to mention a real eye-opener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beware running programs from within visual studio debugger as the LFH (low fragmentation heap) memory allocator is disabled in this case.  Try the software from outside of VS.

I have seen cases where tasks would take seconds to complete normally take hours to complete just by running from within visual studio.

Above all if you still don't know what is going on divide and conquer.  Instrument the app to see runtimes of subsystems or just place debug timers in various areas to see where execution time is changing drastically and drill down from there.  If it is a memory allocator issue you will normally see large runtimes while freeing the arrays.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful comment. I took the exe file, and did separate test outside of VS. Run times are ranging in between 50-70 seconds in all runs. I also ran the code in VS without debugging (CTRL + F5), I am getting the same results. So It's more like the issue is in the debugger of VS.

Comment: @amobishoproden, so you were running your application in the debugger with a debug compile and expecting to get reasonable run times?  A debugger's main purpose is to allow you to see what is going on in the application and to help determine the cause of problems and defects by being able to inspect the running application.  A debug compile also adds additional checks and overhead.  Poor run time using the debugger with a debug compile is not an issue to be laid on Visual Studio.

Comment: I know there are some differences between debug run and normal run. But I wasn't expecting it get this much (quadrupled run times). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Your code runs in an environment, which includes the state of the operating system, disk, network, time, memory, other processes launched, etc.

Executing the same code in the same environment will give the same result, every time.

Now, you're getting different results (execution times). If you're running the same executable repeatedly, then something is changing in the surrounding environment.

Now, the most obvious question is : Is your code causing a change to the outside environment? A simple example would be: It reads in a file, changes the data and writes it back out to the same file.

You know your code. Just use this approach to isolate any effects your code may be having on its environment and you'll find the reason.

Comment: I got what you mean. I am printing the results in separate output files, and never change my output. And I always get the exact same results (except the run time). The issue seems to be from the debugger of VS, as I explained in my comment to the previous answer. Thanks for sparing time for this.